# REST Assured: passing XML Namespace in Request Body

Tags: xml, json, rest

I'm trying to hit a REST api which needs below XML NameSpace in request body.

```
<candidate name="xyz" ldap-alias="abc" ldap-dn="abcd">
<secondary-ref ldap-alias="klm" ldap-dn="abcd"/>
</candidate>
```

My request is:

```
expect().contentType("application/json").expect().statusCode(200).log().all().when().request().contentType("application/json").post("myrequest");
```

Can anyone Please Help?

Thanks,
Ranjeet

Answer (score 0):

This the XML is so small I would probably just paste the XML into a String and pass that to the body of rest assured:

```
String xml = "<candidate name=\"xyz\" ldap-alias=\"abc\" ldap-dn=\"abcd\">\n<secondary-ref ldap-alias=\"klm\" ldap-dn=\"abcd\"/>\n</candidate>";

given().
        contentType(ContentType.XML).
        body(xml).
when().
        post("myrequest").
then().
        statusCode(200).
        contentType(ContentType.JSON);
```